# Как создать фильтр товаров Woocommerce по кастомному полю в админке Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, acf, фильтрация

Нужно как-то реализовать фильтр в админке по кастомному полю.

Небольшое предисловие: это сайт агентства недвижимости и там у них есть выбор агента, который занимается этим объявлением. Я сделал кастомные страницы, привязал полю и сделал там выбор. Всё присваивается и отлично работает в фронтенде.

**Однако, нужно сделать столбец в списке объявлений (Товаров Вукоммерс), которые еще могут фильртоваться, чтобы увидеть, сколько объявлений на определенном агенте. Как это сделать? Подойдет вариант и через код и через плагин. Спасибо!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это точно можно сделать с пом. платной версии плагина [Admin Columns](https://www.admincolumns.com/)

Возможно [WPC Admin Columns](https://wpclever.net/downloads/wpc-admin-columns/) (это новый плагин, его я ещё не пробовал)

А можно и самому написать по аналогии [с фильтром для авторов](https://wp-kama.ru/note/filtr-avtorov-v-tablitse-zapisej)